# Add point to SVG polygon on line closest to click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a React app with an SVG polygon element. The polygon begins its life as a square but new points can be added by double clicking inside the polygon area.

I want the point to be added to the side of the polygon closest to the cursor position of the click event, however since the polygon's points are rendered in clockwise direction starting at the top left, placing the point on the correct line depends on determining which points create the line closest to cursor to be able to splice the point into the correct array index.

So far I have created an algorithm to determine the closest and next closest points, relative to the click event, but this fails in the case where there are multiple points close together on an opposite line.

In the below example clicking along the top portion of the right side causes an additional point to be added between the two closest points, which are the top right corner and the point along the top close to the top right corner. This is incorrect. I want this point to be added between the points that create the right side of the polygon.

[polygon prior to adding point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CXTX.png)

[polygon with point added by clicking along the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2YEm.png)

The solution that I have come up with is to create an array of points along each of the lines created by the polygon points (at an arbitrary distance from each other) and then iterate through each of these arrays for each new point to determine which pair of points creates the line closest to the click event. This seems like it would be very inefficient though.

I have recreated this problem here: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-svg-point-zgt56?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this using point interpolation to subdivide the lines into smaller segments.

https://codesandbox.io/s/add-svg-point-forked-fhz05?file=/src/App.js

Interpolation improves the resolution of the math, and it can still error if two lines are right beside each other. Simply changing the ratio of interpolation could increase resolution even further

```
  for (let n = 0; n < 1; n += 0.05) {
    let interpolatedDist = distance(interpolate(curr, next, n));
    if (interpolatedDist < closestDistance) {
      closestPoint = i;
      closestDistance = interpolatedDist;
    }
  }
```

I stored interpolatedDist to avoid recalculating it.